# Unable to get the length of JSON object

Tags: json, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, dialogflow-es

I am getting 'TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object' while trying to access the length of json object in nodejs.

Following is how my data looks like:

```js
{
  "college": [
    {
      "colleges": [],
      "department": [
        1,
        2,
        3
      ],
      "general_course": [],
      "id": 1,
      "name": "College of the Arts",
      "short_name": "",
      "url": "/content.php?catoid=16&navoid=1919"
    },
    {
      "colleges": [],
      "department": [
        4,
        5,
        6
      ],
      "general_course": [],
      "id": 2,
      "name": "College of Communications",
      "short_name": "",
      "url": "/content.php?catoid=16&navoid=1920"
    },
    {
      "colleges": [],
      "department": [
        7,
        12
      ],
      "general_course": [],
      "id": 3,
      "name": "College of Education",
      "short_name": "",
      "url": "/content.php?catoid=16&navoid=1921"
    },
    {
      "colleges": [],
      "department": [
        13,
        17,
        19
      ],
      "general_course": [],
      "id": 4,
      "name": "College of Engineering and Computer Science",
      "short_name": "",
      "url": "/content.php?catoid=16&navoid=1922"
    },
    {
      "colleges": [],
      "department": [
        20,
        26,
        27
      ],
      "general_course": [],
      "id": 5,
      "name": "College of Health and Human Development",
      "short_name": "",
      "url": "/content.php?catoid=16&navoid=1923"
    },
    {
      "colleges": [],
      "department": [
        28,
        29,
        32,
        48
      ],
      "general_course": [],
      "id": 6,
      "name": "College of Humanities and Social Sciences",
      "short_name": "",
      "url": "/content.php?catoid=16&navoid=1924"
    },
    {
      "colleges": [],
      "department": [
        52,
        57
      ],
      "general_course": [],
      "id": 7,
      "name": "College of Natural Sciences and Mathematics",
      "short_name": "",
      "url": "/content.php?catoid=16&navoid=1925"
    },
    {
      "colleges": [],
      "department": [
        58,
        59,
        63
      ],
      "general_course": [],
      "id": 8,
      "name": "Mihaylo College of Business and Economics",
      "short_name": "",
      "url": "/content.php?catoid=16&navoid=1926"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Step 1** - Parsing it into nodejs:

```
let colleges = JSON.parse(data)
```

**Step 2** - Saving it into the dialogflow app data:

```
app.data.collegeData = data;
```

**Step 3** - Accessing the length:

```
let collegeLength = Object.keys(app.data.collegeData.college).length;
```

Getting following error in firebase console:

> TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

**Update:**

Here is the code:

```js
if ( app.data.collegeData === undefined ){
    app.data.collegeData = [];
}

**Step 1 =>** 

showColleges(college);

**Step 2 =>**

  function showColleges(collegeName){
      if (app.data.collegeData.length === 0){
          getCollegeData().then(buildSingleCollegeResponse(collegeName))
              .catch(function (err){
                  console.log('No college data')
                  console.log(err)
              });
      }
      else{
          buildSingleCollegeResponse(collegeName);
      }
  }

**Step 3 =>**

 function getCollegeData(){
      console.log('Inside get College Data')
      return requestAPI(URL)
          .then(function (data) {
              let colleges = JSON.parse(data)
              if (colleges.hasOwnProperty('college')){
                  saveData(colleges)
              }
              return null;
          })
          .catch(function (err) {
              console.log('No college data')
              console.log(err)
          });
  }

**Step 4 =>**

  function saveData(data){
      app.data.collegeData = data;
      console.log(app.data.collegeData)
  }

**Step 5 =>**

function buildSingleCollegeResponse(collegeName){
      let responseToUser, text;
      //console.log('Data is -> '+ Object.keys(app.data.collegeData.college).length);
      //console.log('Length is -> '+ app.data.collegeData.college.length);
      console.log('Count is -> '+app.data.collegeCount);

      let collegeLength = Object.keys(app.data.collegeData.college).length;

      if ( collegeLength === 0){
          responseToUser = 'No colleges available at this time';
          text = 'No colleges available at this time';
      }
      else if ( app.data.collegeCount < collegeLength ){

          for ( var i = 1; i <= collegeLength; i++)
          {
              console.log('All Colleges:: '+app.data.collegeData.college[i])
              let coll = app.data.collegeData.college[i]
              let name = coll.name
              console.log('checkCollegeExist => College Name:: '+ name)
              console.log('checkCollegeExist => Parameter => College Name:: '+collegeName)

              if(String(name).valueOf() === String(collegeName).valueOf()){
                  responseToUser = 'Yes! CSUF has '+collegeName;
                  text = 'Yes! CSUF has '+collegeName;
              }else{
                  responseToUser = 'CSUF does not teach ' +collegeName+' currently';
                  text = 'CSUF does not teach ' +collegeName+' currently';
              }
          }
      }
      else{
          responseToUser = 'No more colleges';
      }
      if (requestSource === googleAssistantRequest) {
          sendGoogleResponse(responseToUser);
      } else {
          sendResponse(text);
      }
  }
```

Comment: Step 1: `let colleges = JSON.parse(data)`  then Step 2: `app.data.collegeData = data;` Shouldn't that be `= colleges`? `data` is still a string (JSON), but you want to work with the actual data in `colleges` (which is not JSON, since it's not a string).

Comment: Voting to close as typo/non-repro/not-useful-in-future, as it works if you fix the simple mistake above: https://jsfiddle.net/dktaknrc/

Comment: Thanks! Updated my question. Posted some more code, if it helps.

Comment: There's only one JSON object in Javascript and it's used for (de)serializing JSON formatted strings. You either have a JSON formatted string or a JavaScript object.

Comment: @phuzi I dont think there is issue with the JSON. Its a valid JSON and I suppose he is already issuing JSON.parse.

Comment: @ch4nd4n Not quite what I was getting at, the OPs usage of "json object" is incorrect. http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the culprit:

```
getCollegeData().then(buildSingleCollegeResponse(collegeName))
```

That **calls** `buildSingleCollegeResponse(collegeName)` and then passes its *return value* into `then`, just like `foo(bar())` **calls** `bar` and passes its return value into `foo`.

You wanted to pass a functon to `then`:

```
getCollegeData().then(() => buildSingleCollegeResponse(collegeName))
// An arrow function  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

---

Note that now that it's clear from the updated question that `app.data.collegeData.college` is an *array*, there's no need for `Object.keys`. Change:

```
let collegeLength = Object.keys(app.data.collegeData.college).length;
```

to simply

```
let collegeLength = app.data.collegeData.college.length;
```

Arrays have a `length` property (whereas non-array objects don't, by default).

Comment: Ohh.. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned what value `app.data` holds before issuing `app.data.collegeData = data;`

If `app.data` is undefined you should try `app.data = {collegeData: data}`

Or else negating what app stores. Following works

```
app = {};
app.data = {};
app.data.collegeData = data;

app.data.collegeData.college.length
```

You don't need to do the following

```
let collegeLength = Object.keys(app.data.collegeData.college).length;
```

**Update**: Refer to https://jsfiddle.net/dmxuum79/3/

Comment: @PuneetJain you did not answer if `app.data` is a valid object. If unless app.data is valid, you cannot assign app.data.collegeData.

Comment: Who ever down voted, care to explain why it has been down voted?

Comment: Yup, its valid.

Comment: getCollegeData().then(buildSingleCollegeResponse(collegeName))

This was the issue. Thanks though!